# How to calculate gradient with AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file which includes two columns such as:

```
A B
1 2
10 20
100 200
.
.
.
```

I want to calculate gradient (or slope) dB/dA by awk. It means the third column should be the difference between each adjacent rows in column B divides on difference between each corresponding adjacent rows in column A. The results for above date should be:

```
A B dB/dA
1 2 (20-2)/(10-1)=2
10 20 (200-20)/(100-10)=2
100 200 
.
. 
.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your files, you can do this :

```
$cat file
A B
1 2
10 20
100 200


awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}NR==1{print $1,$2,"dA/dB"}NR>2{print a,b,($2-b)/($1-a)}{a=$1;b=$2}' file
A   B   dA/dB
1   2   2
10  20  2
100 200 2
```

With :

- `BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` to set Output Field Separator to tab
- `NR==1{print $1,$2,"dA/dB"}` to copy the header and add the grad column
- `NR>2` to skip the header and the first line as you want to start from the second row (of value)
- `{a=$1;b=$2}` to save values in `a` and `b`, for next line. This part works from the 1st line
- `{print a,b,($2-b)/($1-a)}` print the previous line and the gradient between this line and the previous

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. how to add header?

Comment: Add header using `NR==1{print $0,"dB/dA"}`